# CollectionView Not Loaded Until I Scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So I am having an issue with my collectionView. Currently the setup I have is one where there are two sections. The data that goes in each section is being pulled from some database and then based into those respective sections.

Below is the code for my main homeFeedController

```
class HomeFeedController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    // let dropDownLauncher = DropDownLauncher()
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    var isFinishedPaging = false
    var userLocation: CLLocation?
    var allEvents = [Event]()
    var eventKeys = [String]()
    var featuredEvents = [Event]()
    private let cellID = "cellID"
    private let catergoryCellID = "catergoryCellID"
    var images: [String] = ["gear1","gear4","snakeman","gear4","gear1"]
        var images1: [String] = ["sage","sagemode","kyubi","Naruto_Part_III","team7"]
    var featuredEventsHeaderString = "Featured Events"
    var categories : [String] = ["Seize The Night","Seize The Day","21 & Up", "Friends Events"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        navigationItem.title = "Featured Events"
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        grabUserLoc()
        collectionView?.register(HomeFeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
                collectionView?.register(CategoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: catergoryCellID)
       // reloadHomeFeed()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
//        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        print("EventDetailViewController class removed from memory")
    }




    @objc func grabUserLoc(){

        LocationService.getUserLocation { (location) in
            guard let currentLocation = location else {
                return
            }
            PostService.showEvent(for: currentLocation, completion: { [unowned self](events) in
                self.allEvents = events
                print("Event count in PostService Closure:\(self.allEvents.count)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   // self.dynamoCollectionView.reloadData()
                    //self.dynamoCollectionViewTop.reloadData()
                }

            })

            PostService.showFeaturedEvent(for: currentLocation, completion: { [unowned self] (events) in

                self.featuredEvents = events
                print("Event count in Featured Events Closure is:\(self.featuredEvents.count)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // self.dynamoCollectionView.reloadData()
                   // self.dynamoCollectionViewTop.reloadData()
                }
            }
            )
            print("Latitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
            print("Longitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
        }

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! HomeFeedCell
            cell.sectionNameLabel.text = "Featured Events"
            cell.featuredEvents = featuredEvents
            return cell
        }

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: catergoryCellID, for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        cell.sectionNameLabel.text = categories[indexPath.item]
        print(categories[indexPath.item])
        print(indexPath.item)
        cell.categoryEvents = allEvents
        return cell

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 1{
            return 4
        }
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
             return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 300)
        }
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 290)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        if section == 0 {
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        }
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 8)
    }
```

The cells that are created in this home feed controller have collectionViews in each of them which create some sort of a scrollable grid layout. Also each cell is passed an event which contains the information that it needs to render out most of it's cells. The basic layout for my cell is below.

```
import UIKit

class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    private let cellID = "cellID"
    var categoryEvents: [Event]?{
        didSet{
            categoryCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    var titles: String? {
        didSet {
            guard let titles = titles else {
                return
            }
             sectionNameLabel.text = titles
        }
    }


    let sectionNameLabel : UILabel =  {
        let sectionNameLabel = UILabel()
        sectionNameLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)
        return sectionNameLabel
    }()

    let categoryCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .clear
        return cv
    }()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let currentEventCount = categoryEvents?.count else{
            return 0
        }
        return currentEventCount
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! CategoryEventCell
        cell.event = categoryEvents?[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 200, height: frame.height - 30)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 14, bottom: 0, right: 14)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    @objc func setupViews(){
        backgroundColor = .clear
        addSubview(categoryCollectionView)
        addSubview(sectionNameLabel)
        sectionNameLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 14, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
                categoryCollectionView.anchor(top: sectionNameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
                categoryCollectionView.delegate = self
                categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self
                categoryCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        categoryCollectionView.register(CategoryEventCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)

    }
}
```

This cell which contains a collectionView ultimately passes a specific event to a cell which ultimately takes whats needed to render itself. The code for that is below.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class CategoryEventCell: BaseRoundedCardCell {

    var event: Event? {
    didSet{
        guard let currentEvent = event else {
            return
        }
        guard let url = URL(string: currentEvent.currentEventImage) else { return }
        backgroundImageView.af_setImage(withURL: url)
        eventNameLabel.text = currentEvent.currentEventName.capitalized
    }
    }

    public var backgroundImageView: CustomImageView = {
        let firstImage = CustomImageView()
        firstImage.clipsToBounds = true
        firstImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        firstImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        firstImage.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        return firstImage
    }()

    let eventNameLabel : UILabel =  {
        let sectionNameLabel = UILabel()
        sectionNameLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 14.0)
        return sectionNameLabel
    }()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    @objc func setupViews(){
        backgroundColor = .clear
       // setCellShadow()
        addSubview(backgroundImageView)
        addSubview(eventNameLabel)
        backgroundImageView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(600), for: .vertical)
        backgroundImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: eventNameLabel.topAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        eventNameLabel.anchor(top: backgroundImageView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

The issue seems to come with the loading of the content for some reason on the start of the app none of the content loads. But as soon as I scroll everything begins to load up. In addition to that, there is a section that doesn't even load up any content at all when the rest of them does. I want all of the cells to load their content when I enter the screen not when I scroll. I apologize if this is a rookie mistake but this is just not behaving the way I want it to. There was also one time where the UI actually locked up. My current UI looks like this. Any help is appreciated. This has been bothering me for hours

I understand that collectionViews load when a cell is within view the problem is none of them loads until I scroll down or up whatever the direction may be.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView works such away that install of a cell at index path will be only present when it is within the display. if cell is out of the visible collection view. cell will br dqqued to reuse for another index. So when you are fetching data with each cell.. at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` All cells are not created only visible cells are created.

You can make advatage of Collection view Prefetch functionality to load data just before it go to present.

You can refer more details for prefetch UICollectionView

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/uicollectionview-prefetching-in-ios-10

Comment: even if it only loads when within view. All of them not loading at all is the main issue